# Is it possible for one application not running as root to send keystrokes to the terminal application?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, security, root

I use Ubuntu linux. Lets say I accidentally downloaded a malicious program which has the ability to record keystrokes. Because of this, now this program got access to my sudo password. Now, can this program run other programs with root access? For example, can it send a sudo command to a terminal application and when prompted for a password, can it send my password by simulating key presses sent to the terminal application?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that with pseudo-terminals. It's how programs like the SSH server, GNU screen and all GUI terminal emulators work to present a terminal to the programs they run.

With `screen`, it's somewhat simple to test that yourself:
Start a `screen` session, then run `screen -X 'sudo id\nsecretpassword\n'` (from inside or outside that `screen`).

You'll see the command and its output appear in the `screen` session:

```
$ sudo id
[sudo] password for ilkkachu:
uid=0(root) gid=0(root) groups=0(root)
$
```